Spring Cloud Function with Multiple Beans
I'm building a Spring Cloud Function application with multiple functions (e.g., uppercase, reverse, etc.) for deployment as an AWS Lambda. The function is triggered by data received from AWS IoT Core, and I need to route the invocation dynamically based on a header or event payload.
Issue
When I run the application locally or deploy it, I encounter the following warning:
WARN  - Multiple functional beans were found [uppercase, reverse1, reverse], thus can't determine default function definition.

What I've Tried:
spring.cloud.function.routing-expression=#request.headers['functionName']
How can I configure Spring Cloud Function to handle multiple functional beans and dynamically to route based on a header or event payload, avoiding the can't determine default function warning?
